# Python: How to implent Generator in a class method by this class instances

Tags: python

in the following code

```
class Student(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.vals=[9,2,4,1]

   def allstudents(self):
      self.vals.sort()
      for s in self.vals:
            yield s
```

`jack = Student()`

`jack.allstudents().next()` -> Of course the output is 1

`jack.allstudents().next()` -> Here is the problem: this line's output is still 1. Why not 2?

`jack.allstudents().next()` -> This line's output is still 1. Why not 4?

Could anyone give me an explanation, please?

Comment: Note that it would be conventional to implement the `__iter__` *"magic method"*, then you can just do e.g. `for s in jack:`

Comment: please see [this SO QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python) dedicated to `yield`

Answer (score 3):

Because you are constantly calling the `allstudents()` method again and again. Try storing it in a variable and then calling `next()` on the variable assigned to it, like:

```
var = jack.allstudents()
var.next()
var.next()
```

and so on.

Comment: Additionally, you might want to replace `for s in self.vals:yield s` with `yield from self.vals` for performance.

Comment: thx guy! I got it~ sorry for replying late, since I have been out recently!